# How to stop jest updateSnapshot from replacing `<Measure` to `<_class`

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This is something that has shown up very recently.

[image]

node: v9

react-measure: 2.0.2

Comment: What version of react and jest are you using? Also, have you tried to set `displayName` on `Measure` to see if that fixes anything?

Comment: @MattyJ I'm using `react 16.6.0` and `jest 21.2.1`. `Measure` is a component imported from third party component called `react-measure`. So I won't  be able to add `displayName`. I'm using `react-measure` version 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

The logic for printing React components usually goes something like this:

```
output = Component.displayName || Component.name;
```

So, the first thing to check when something like this happens is what are those 2 variables.

---

It looks like for `react-measure@2.0.2` the exported `Measure` component has a `displayName` of `undefined` and a `name` of `_class`.

It looks like in the latest version (`v2.2.2`) the `displayName` has been set, so the snapshot will return `<Measure>` as you'd expect.

They don't really talk about this change in their [changelog](https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), but I would try it out and hopefully it doesn't break what you are trying to do.

---

An alternative (but much less encouraged) way would be to set the `displayName` on the `Measure` component yourself. It's as simple as just assigning `Measure.displayName = 'Measure'`. There aren't *usually* any repercussions to this, but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the version update, I updated the version number of react-measure to 2.2.2 and now the snapshot replaces `<Measure>` with `<Component>` instead of `<_class>`

Comment: Oh yes, I see that. You would have to fully `mount` the component to see all of the children rendered. `shallow` will only render so deeply.

Comment: I'm currently using mount to render the components. Not sure why I still see <Component>

Comment: It looks like the Measure component is just wrapping your component inside another one, which may be different than what they were doing in v2.0.2